# SQL Server Maintenance Cleanup Task

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

Question on what actually the "Maintenance Cleanup Task" does.   When the process executes I see xp_delete removing files but does the task also remove any entries from tables within MSDB?

The reason I ask is the backup appliance we use for SQL, and all other enterprise backups seems to be having issues when we try to delete backup files using the "Maintenance Cleanup Task" running off 50-60 sql instances at roughly the same time.  While I know this is configuration/hardware/vendor issue with our backup appliance I just want to know if this maintenance task does other things that wouldn't be accomplished by a PS script removing old backup (bak/trn) older than a specific date.    Looking at stop gap options till we can work with the appliance vendor to come up with a better long term fix.

I know we could spread out the tasks to clean up old files but the main question is scripting the deletion of an old backup not accomplishing everything the "maintenance cleanup task" does.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: What does "seems to be having issues" mean? Also do you know for sure it's necessary to run both the maintenance plan and the enterprise backup? Does the "enterprise" backup not come with any cleanup functionality of its own? (If not then it doesn't sound very enterprise-y).

Comment: You mention the Enterprise Backups and Maintenance Cleanup Task, but you have not revealed which product you are using just in case it matters. FWIW, I use a SQL Agent task to delete backups when they are ready to age out.  That just points out that there are several ways to "clean up."

Comment: You could do everything the cleanup task does and much much more with Powershell. 

What do you need/want to do exactly and I would love to know what software solution you are using currently, because most products have these types of routines incorperated by default, like @AaronBertrand and RLF also mentioned.

Comment: the issue is while it's deduping/compressing data the I/O to copy/backup/restore drastically drops causing various issues.  So the question is would using PS or something to delete backups do the exact same thing that this maintenance plan does?   Still not sure if that maintenance plan cleans anything up in MSDB

Comment: I 100% sure performance/errors etc. are related to the backup appliance since as a test we modified jobs to backup to a standard file share and clean up tasks etc. work without issue, so again looking for a short term fix to clean up old backup files unless the vendor can work with us to resolve the issue.   I don't want bring up the name of the product as my intent is not to start a conversation on the pros/cons of it.   thanks!